# How to chain playing of several HTML5 audio files like a smooth playlist?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

Given access to valid audio files :

```
<audio src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9b/Zh-Tianjin.ogg"></audio>
<audio src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8a/Zh-Beijing.ogg"></audio>
<audio src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/73/Zh-Shanghai.ogg"></audio>
<audio src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e2/Zh-Chengdu.ogg"></audio>
```

**Given a button :**

```
<button id="play">Play me!</button>
```

**Given I successfully play one audio**

```
$('#play').on('click', function () {
    $("audio")[0].play();
});
```

**How to chain the playing of these several audio, one after an other ?** -- pure JS and JQuery, other JS libs acceptable.

My starting point is **[this fiddle with basic tools](http://jsfiddle.net/2DWkM/2/)**

---

**Edit:** I previously tried a big hand of ways without success, using `.duration`, [`window.setTimeout(function(){do_that}, time_ms)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout), [`.delay()`](https://api.jquery.com/delay/) in few combinations without success. See: http://jsfiddle.net/Ka2Nh/7/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [ended event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events) and trigger the next one

```
var active = false;

$("audio").on("ended", function(){ 
    var audio = $(this).next("audio");
    if (audio.length) {
        audio.get(0).play();   
    } else {
        active = false;   
    }
});

$('#play').on('click', function () {    
    if (!active) {
        $("audio")[0].play();
        active = true;
    }
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yMAs6/1/

Comment: Elegant and effective~